# What's the meaning of "a trimmed down value for PATH env var" in the Anaconda release notes?

Tags: python, anaconda, path-variables

I uninstalled "Anaconda3 5.2.0" and reinstalled "Anaconda3 2020.07" on my Windows computer two days ago. As recommended by the installer, when I installed Anaconda3 5.2.0 last year or reinstalled Anaconda3 2020.07 two day ago, I didn't add Anaconda path to the system `path` environment variable. Things go well when I use python from Anaconda Prompt because the Prompt has added Anaconda directories to the `path` variable.

However, I find a strange different behavior between Anaconda3 5.2.0 and Anaconda3 2020.07 when used outside the Anaconda Prompt. I have a `bat` file containing a single line `C:\Anaconda3\python xxx.py`, and in `xxx.py` I import several python packages including `numpy`. When I used Anaconda 5.2.0, this `bat` file can be executed successfully by double-click (It's equivalent to running `C:\Anaconda3\python xxx.py` in an ordinary CMD, which doesn't know the Anaconda path). However, after I reinstalled Anaconda3 2020.07, I get a `DLL load failed` error when runing this `bat` file because the `numpy` package can't be successfully imported.

I'm sure the error is caused by the `path` variable and I realized that getting the `DLL load failed` error should be a reasonable result when running `C:\Anaconda3\python xxx.py` in ordinary CMD because the `DLL` can't be found without Anaconda directories added to the `path` variable in CMD.

My question is why it can be executed successfully under Anaconda 5.2.0. What's special about Anaconda 5.2.0? Why can the command find those `DLL` files in the ordinary CMD?

Then I checked the [release notes](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/reference/release-notes/) of Anaconda. Under the [Anaconda 5.2.0 part](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/reference/release-notes/#anaconda-5-2-0-may-30-2018), I read the following:

> Windows installer uses a trimmed down value for PATH env var, to avoid DLL hell with existing software

I guess that this may be the reason. But I can't understand the meaning of `a trimmed down value for PATH env var`. Does anyone know how Anaconda 5.2.0 deals with the `path` variable so the python interpreter can find correct `DLL` even outside the Anaconda Prompt in an ordinary CMD?

---

p.s.

The `DLL load failed` error is not specific to `numpy` package. I just take it as an example.

When importing `numpy` in `xxx.py`, the error is (last line):

`Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarry_umath: The specified module could not be found.`

If importing `sqlite3` in `xxx.py`, the error is (last line):

`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Other packages may also cause similar problem. The point is that the python interpreter used outside Anaconda Prompt (by writing the full path `C:\Anaconda3\python xxx.py`, or by using `py xxx.py` if the Python Launcher is also installed) can find correct `DLL` under Anaconda3 5.2.0 but can not find correct `DLL` under Anaconda3 2020.07, though the Anaconda directories are not added to the system `path` variable in both cases.

---

This is an example of `xxx.py`.

```
import numpy
import sqlite3
print('Hello World!')
```

Comment: Could it be that you need to add more folders to path ? What is the content of your variable `PATH` ?

Comment: My `path` variable doesn't include any Anaconda directories. Thus I expect to get an error when running `C:\Anaconda3\python xxx.py` in CMD.

Comment: What is your question ? Is it the one in the title or the one in the middle of your text?

Comment: @Tim Sorry for the confusing. I think the question in the title and the one in the middle of text are related. Understanding the meaning of 'a trimmed down value for PATH env var' may help me understand why Anaconda3 5.2.0 can find DLL in CMD.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, *trimming down* probably means *simplifying*, to make it easier to find out why your `PATH` does not help in finding what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Then how does this simplifying make Anaconda3 5.3.0 able to find the related DLL in CMD where no Anaconda directories are added to `path`?

Comment: It does not, it makes it easier to *you*: the less there is, the more obvious the lack of the required path appears. I think that's the idea.